# Conditional Fields not working with ckeditor?

Tags: 7

i have a problem with conditional fields module in d7: Fields are not hidden when the ckeditor is activated for the certain field...if i switch to "plain text editor" everyting works fine... is that a bug or is it me not setting the right options...?

Comment: It doesn't really help now but it would be worth following this issue - http://drupal.org/node/1868838

Comment: I think it's more than a bug with conditional fields - CKeditor doesn't work with FAPI `#states` at all

Comment: @Clive thanks for clarification! How would you handle this cases with wysiwyg fields? Code it into the ckeditor config.js which I'm trying to do currently ;-P

Comment: The couple of times it's happened I just wired up the js event for the checkbox to manually show/hide the wysiwyg, very low-tech. I'm surprised not to be able to find more about this on google